# How to Draw a Bezier Curve in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I need to make a curve in a `UIView` as displayed in the image below. I have to use `UIBezierPath`. Kindly help me out with this.

I also want to know how to flip the curve from the horizontal axis, so that I have the arc at the top and the base at the bottom.

[image: Example of bezier path]

Comment: Refer this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/34003/core-graphics-tutorial-curves-and-layers

Comment: I think this link is useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904767/drawing-a-bezier-curve-between-a-set-of-given-points

Comment: is their any restriction on using Image as curve ? @Diksha

Comment: @RahulMishra i have to use UIView rather than image

Comment: @Diksha You can Use a `UIView` and Put an `UIImageView` inside it..and Place a image having curve.  I have done same functionality

Comment: @RahulMishra You have used Image on imageview or you have done through beizerpath

Comment: @Diksha I have taken a white Image having same curve and Applied to ImageView and then Positioned the UIImage VIew accordingly...

Comment: @Diksha Do you have this white Curve Image ?

Comment: @RahulMishra no i have to execute the task with beizerpath

Comment: @Diksha I haven't used Bezire Curve. I will try if I get this curve then will post my answer

Comment: @Diksha Even If you make A curve then How can You acheive same UI as shown in Image.... Bezire curve will only add a curve. How will you cut the map part under the curve.

Comment: I will put my view over the mapview thus it will look like the map under the curve

Comment: @Diksha If you can manage to get a Image have curve then it will takes minutes to make this UI.... Just Make A UIVIew as a container of MapView and CurveImageView....Make MapView frame equal to Parent View and at the top put your ImageView..

Comment: @RahulMishra No rahul,actually i have to do it without image.I know it would be easy with image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114639/discussion-between-rahulmishra-and-diksha).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To draw a solid filled in arc within a particular `CGSize`, you can define a `UIBezierPath` like so:

```
- (UIBezierPath * _Nullable)pathOfArcWithinSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (size.width == 0 || size.height <= 0) return nil;

    CGFloat theta = M_PI - atan2(size.width / 2.0, size.height) * 2.0;
    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.height / (1.0 - cos(theta));

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, -radius + size.height) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI_2 + theta endAngle:M_PI_2 - theta clockwise:false];
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}
```

That's just using a little trigonometry to calculate the angle and radius for the arc given the height and width of the view.

Once you have that, you can either construct a `CAShapeLayer` using that path and then add that as a sublayer of a `UIView` or you can implement your own `drawRect` method that calls `fill` on that path. (Or, given that you've tagged this with [core-graphics](/questions/tagged/core-graphics), you could also do a custom `drawRect` with CoreGraphics calls, but I'm not sure why you'd do that.)

For example, you could define a `CurvedView` class that uses `CAShapeLayer`:

```
//  CurvedView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CurvedView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *fillColor;

@end
```

And

```
//  CurvedView.m

#import "CurvedView.h"

@interface CurvedView ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) CAShapeLayer *curvedLayer;
@end

@implementation CurvedView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configureView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self configureView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configureView {
    self.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer.fillColor = self.fillColor.CGColor;
    layer.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    layer.lineWidth = 0;
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer];
    self.curvedLayer = layer;
}

- (void)setFillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor {
    _fillColor = fillColor;

    self.curvedLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.curvedLayer.path = [self pathOfArcWithinSize:self.bounds.size].CGPath;
}

- (UIBezierPath * _Nullable)pathOfArcWithinSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (size.width == 0 || size.height <= 0) return nil;

    CGFloat theta = M_PI - atan2(size.width / 2.0, size.height) * 2.0;
    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.height / (1.0 - cos(theta));

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, -radius + size.height) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI_2 + theta endAngle:M_PI_2 - theta clockwise:false];
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}

@end
```

That yields:

[image]

Or, if you'd rather use the `drawRect` approach rather than using `CAShapeLayer`:

```
//  CurvedView.m

#import "CurvedView.h"

@implementation CurvedView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configureView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self configureView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configureView {
    self.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)setFillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor {
    _fillColor = fillColor;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *path = [self pathOfArcWithinSize:self.bounds.size];
    [self.fillColor setFill];
    [path fill];
}

- (UIBezierPath * _Nullable)pathOfArcWithinSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (size.width == 0 || size.height <= 0) return nil;

    CGFloat theta = M_PI - atan2(size.width / 2.0, size.height) * 2.0;
    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.height / (1.0 - cos(theta));

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, -radius + size.height) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI_2 + theta endAngle:M_PI_2 - theta clockwise:false];
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}

@end
```

---

If you want the arc to occupy the bottom of the view, the path would look like:

```
- (UIBezierPath * _Nullable)pathOfArcWithinSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (size.width == 0 || size.height <= 0) return nil;

    CGFloat theta = M_PI - atan2(size.width / 2.0, size.height) * 2.0;
    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.height / (1.0 - cos(theta));

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, size.height)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, radius) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI_2 * 3.0 + theta endAngle:M_PI_2 * 3.0 - theta clockwise:false];
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}
```

Essentially, that's the same `theta` and `radius`, but start in lower left corner, set the `center` to be `size.width / 2.0, radius`, and arc from `M_PI_2 * 3.0` ± `theta`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks rob..you saved me again..i want to learn this..actually dont know how to deal with UIBeizers,i want to learn this,so can you help me from where can i start...thanks...:)

Comment: @Elan - For the basics of bezier paths, see Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW1) or google "uibezierpath tutorial". For the maths to achieve the desired path, this is drawing on my old high-school trigonometry from the mists of time. :) Bottom line, just start playing around with building your own `UIBezierPath` in either custom `UIView` subclass (like above) or `CAShapeLayer` and I'm sure you'll pick it up quickly. It's not as hard as it looks.